# use variable in .js and .html

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website in html and I have an external .js file. There is a array in the .js file that I would like to display in the website as a list so will need to get the array into the html file but I do not know how to.

My html:

I would like the array in this tag

```
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

My external js:

```
    fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

Is there anyway to use the variable in the html file or can I display the array as a list in the js file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: an example of your case https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want to display them, but mainly you want to use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to place them within the element.

```js
let p = document.getElementById('demo');

let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

p.innerHTML = fruits.join('<br>');
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

You could also do it this way and make a unordered list:

```js
let p = document.getElementById('demo');

let fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

p.innerHTML = fruits.map(i => `<li>${i}</li>`).join('');
```

```html
<ul id="demo"></ul>
```

Comment: I think pointing Neesh to a place where he can learn basics of combining Javascript and HTML would be a better answer than actually providing a simple code snippet :-)

Comment: If I wanted to display it in an ordered list how would I do that?

Comment: By changing the `ul` tag to an `ol` tag.

Comment: Can I display it in a table if I had another array for colours?

Comment: @Neesh by accepting answers, you can gain reputation. It also lets people know you found an answer for the current question.